# Unable to click on ShareAction Provider

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am trying to click on the ShareActionProvider button on my mobile, but it is completely unresponsive. None of the sharing apps such as texting or emailing pop up. I've labeled the ShareActionProvider as menu_share in my xml file, and am using the method onOptionsItemSelected to respond to any clicks.

Java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{
        ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
        //String[] parsedWeatherData;
        ShareActionProvider provider;


public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
       MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
       provider = (ShareActionProvider)      
       MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_share:
                Log.d("Weather", "Is menu share clicked");
                doShare();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

public void doShare() {
        String message = oneDayWeather;

        // populate the share intent with data


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        provider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }
```

XML

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bwq="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:title="@string/menu_share"
        bwq:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        bwq:showAsAction="always"/>


</menu>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it. This version of ShareActionProvider only works if you set the setShareIntent method right after getting the provider. For example:

```
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
        provider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        provider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
```